# Problem with simultaneous equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given that $(5, h)$ is a solution of the simultaneous equations $h(x-y) = x + y -1 = hx^2 - 11y^2$, find
>
> (a) the value of $h$.
>
> (b) the other solution of the equation.(x and y)

I don't really understand the question. What does $(5, h)$ is the solution means?

Shouldn't simultaneous equations have $1$ solution only (e.g. $5$)?

**EDIT:** I found that $h = 2$.

Now I'm having problem at (b). Here are my steps.

$h(x-y) = x + y - 1 = hx^2 - 11y^2$

$2(x-y) = 2x - 2y$ -- 1

$x + y - 1$ so $ x = -y + 1$ -- 2

After I substitute 2 into 1, I got $y = -1/2$

I don't think my answer is correct, please help me.

Comment: The solution is $x=5,y=h$.

Comment: @Michael Does that mean (5, h) = (x, y)? I can substitute it right?

Comment: Yes.  As other solutions have shown, you should get $h=2$.  Then go back to the start and put $h=2$ in instead, then solve $2(x-y)=x+y-1=2x^2-11y^2$ for $x$ and $y$, to get the 'other solution'.

Comment: In your second line after Now I'm having, you say $2(x-y)=2x-y$ while it should be $2(x-y)=2x-2y$

Comment: @RossMillikan Oh, that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Your line 2 doesn't make sense.  You are setting $x+y-1=0$ without justification when you say so...  You need to say $2(x-y)=x+y-1, 2(x-y)=2x^2-11y^2$ and solve the simultaneous equations.  You will get a solution different from $x=5, y=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

We have $$h(5-h)=5+h-1=h(5^2)-11(h^2)$$

From $h(5-h)=5+h-1$, $$h^2-4h+4=0$$

From $5+h-1=h(5^2)-11(h^2),$  $$11h^2-24h+4=0$$

Find the common roots

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I am having another problem. Please see the edited question above.

Comment: @Jeremy, $$h(x-y)=x+y-1\implies2(x-y)=x+y-1\iff x-3y+1=0$$

Comment: That means $x = 3y - 1$?

Answer (score 1):

$(5,h)$ is a singular solution, most likely in this case $x = 5, y = h$.

Plugging these in:
$$h(5 - h) = 5 + h - 1 = h+4\implies h^2 - 4h + 4 = 0 \implies h = 2$$

So, $x =5, y = 2$ or '$(5,2)$'

EDIT: In consideration of your edit to the problem:
$x = 5, h = 2$$$h(x-y) = 2(5-y) = 5 + y - 1 = x + y - 1$$
$$2(5-y) = 5+y - 1 \implies 3y = 6$$

So $y = 2 = h$ Note that this should not be a surprise! You know that $(x,y) = (5,h)$ is a solution to the equation. Subbing in $x = 5$ we should find $y = h$

Comment: Thanks for your solution(I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation). I am having another problem. Please see the edited question above.

Comment: @jeremy see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables, $x$ and $y$, and one parameter, $h$.  You are told that the solution is $x=5, y=h$ and have two equations because of the two equals signs.  You are expected to solve the two equations $h(x-y)=x=y-1, h(x-y)=hx^2-1y^2$, viewing $h$ as a constant.  You will get a solution where $x$ and $y$ are functions of $h$.  Then if you require $x=5$ you will get and equation for $h$.  Solve it and report the value of $h$ that comes out.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation helps me a lot(I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation). I am having another problem. Please see the edited question above.